# Display the next option in array with button for a quiz

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have searched extensively with no answer in plain JavaScript. I'm building a quiz app with dynamically displayed questions and radio button choices.

I can't figure out how to link the code. I want to make sure the user has selected an option, if they have then clicking the next button will display the next question in the array and store the answer.

I have put an alert where I think the code needs to go.

Thanks

```js
    //store all the questions in an array
    var allQuestions = [{
                        question: "How many legs does a spider have?",
                        choices: [6, 4, 8],
                        correctAnswer:8},
                        {
                        question: "how many legs does a cat have?",
                        choices: [2, 4, 6],
                        correctAnswer:4},
                        {
                        question: "how many legs do you have?",
                        choices: [2, 4, 6],
                        correctAnswer:2
                        }];



    var container = document.getElementById('container')
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var questions = document.getElementById('questions');
    var choicesContainer = document.getElementById("choices");
    var scoreContainer = document.getElementById('score');
    var sumitButton = document.getElementById('next');
    var questionHeading = document.getElementById("h2");
    var nextButton = document.getElementById("next"); // next button
    var i = 0;
    //start of quiz
    var currentQuestion = 0;
    var score = 0;
    var questionAsked = true;

    // loop through choices, and create radio buttons

    // function to askQuestion
    showChoices()

    function askQuestion () {
    var askQuestions = allQuestions[currentQuestion].question;
       document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = askQuestions;
    }

    askQuestion()

    // display the iterative choices
            function showChoices() {
                var displayChoices = allQuestions[currentQuestion].choices;
                for (var i = 0; i < displayChoices.length; i++) {
                    var label = document.createElement('label');
                    var input = document.createElement('input');

                    var br = document.createElement('br');

                    input.setAttribute("id", "Radios");
                    input.setAttribute('type', 'radio');
                    input.setAttribute('name', 'answer');
                    input.setAttribute('value', i);

                    label.appendChild(input);
                    label.appendChild(document.createTextNode(displayChoices[i]));

                    container.append(label);

                    container.append(br);
                }
            }

    //select next button
    (function(){

      var myNode = document.querySelector('#next');


      myNode.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

      if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON'){

        alert("nextquestion");

      }

      }, false); // item is clicked

    })(); //self executing function


    //check if a radio is checked

    function buttonChecked () {
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('answer');
    var value;
    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].type === 'radio' && radios[i].checked) {
            // get value, set checked flag or do whatever you need to
            value = radios[i].value;
          }
        }

    }


    // function getRadioInfo() {
    // //get the users radio button answer
    //
    // var e = document.getElementById("choices");
    // var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    // var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    // // store the users answers in a variable
```

```html
    <body>

      <div id="container">
        <div id="content"></div>
            <div id="allQuestions"></div>
                <div id="question"></div>
                    <div id="choices"></div>
                        <div id="score"></div>
      </div>

      <button id="next">Next</button>

    </body>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Jafoolee/pen/rWBOVQ?editors=1010)

Comment: Without going into details of your code, I would say that you need to add eventListener to your radio buttons to change display status of next button. Or you can add eventListener to their container and on click check if any of the children are checked and if so, show next button.

Comment: Maybe you're not going to use an MVVM framework (it would be easy if you opted to use an MVVM framwork). With the code you have, you need to write some bindings for those radio buttons and you current question object (some kind of even listener, maybe). Then when you click NEXT, check the current question object, see if it has been answered yet, then proceed accordingly. (Well, I am not sure that is what you want or something else)

Comment: Thanks for having a look. completely missed that I haven't added event listeners to the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First issue, you are appending `choices` to `container`. It should be `choices.append`.

Second, before appending, clear contents of choices.

Then, you can do:

```js
if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
  currentQuestion++;
  askQuestion()
  showChoices();
}
```

Also, instead of calling directly, you should call functions that deal with DOM on page load

```
window.addEventListener('load',showQuestion)
```

Note: I have created a wrapper to call both functions

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/f2kjtfwo/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will add this to my current code and keep trying to get it all to work together.